# lme output interpretation when including a varIdent(~ 1 | subject)

Tags: mixed-model, variance, repeated-measures, variability

I am working on a project where I want to determine the sources of variability. I built the following model using the nlme package and lme function:

```
model <- lme(response ~ time,
         random = ~1 | subject,
         weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | subject),
         data = mydata)
```

I have included the `varIdent(form = ~ 1 | subject)` to allow for variance across the subject to vary. So the output I get is the following:

```
    Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: mydata 
       AIC     BIC    logLik
  1247.404 1330.13 -597.7019

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | subject
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    10.89967 11.59247

Variance function:
 Structure: Different standard deviations per stratum
 Formula: ~1 | subject
 Parameter estimates:
   subject1     subject2  subject3      subject4   subject5    subject6      subject7   subject8  subject9      subject10 subject11 
1.0000000 0.3876824 0.6345513 0.4247540 0.2606844 0.3131742 0.5792395 0.4509333 0.6265211 0.2278633 0.2664882 
    subject12 subject13   subject14  subject15  subject16     subject17   subject18 subject19   subject20  subject21     subject22 
0.4478437 0.6063039 0.4480821 0.8017382 0.7483262 0.6244823 0.3300986 0.5452207 0.3177361 0.4945264 0.3340157 
    subject23 
0.2787269 
Fixed effects:  response ~ time 
                Value Std.Error  DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept) 126.08026  2.361747 156 53.38433       0
time         -0.43716  0.046918 156 -9.31751       0
 Correlation: 
     (Intr)
time -0.193

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-2.4749799 -0.7253832  0.1031940  0.6567624  2.2570579 

Number of Observations: 180
Number of Groups: 23
```

My understanding is that the within-subject variability is the residual which is 11.59. However, I don't understand how this value is related to the individual SD's. I extracted the individual SD's using:

```
library(mixedup)
data.frame(extract_het_var(model, scale = "sd"))
```

For example, if I calculate the mean SD between individuals, the value is 5.6. I am not sure if it is the correct approach, but, in general, the individual SD's are quite smaller than the 11.59 residual.

On the other hand, if I run a model without the **weights** argument, the residual I get from the output is 6.5. Can someone explain to me where I miss it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model with the `weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | subject)` argument specifies that the within-subject variance differs from subject to subject. The 11.59 is the within-subject 1 standard deviation, and the values in the 'Variance Function' part of the output denote the ratios of the standard deviation of each of the other subjects versus the standard deviation of Subject 1. That is, the standard deviation for Subject 2 is 0.3876824 * 11.59247.

The between-subjects standard deviation is 10.89967.